# Oracle JET CLI "ojet" not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, npm, oracle-jet

After installing ojet with `npm -g install @oracle/oraclejet`, I get the following error when calling ojet command:

> '**ojet**' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please display the output of running the npm command. What OS are you on? What version of NPM are you running?

Comment: My device OS: Windows 10
Npm version: 5.6.0

and i cant use this package to show the output. you can see it there, http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/globalGetStarted.html

Comment: Rerun the npm install command. Copy and paste the output of running the command to your question.

Comment: **Command**: npm -g install @oracle/ojet-cli
**Output**: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\ojet -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@oracle\ojet-cli\ojet.js

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@oracle\ojet-cli\node_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall

+ @oracle/ojet-cli@4.1.0
added 397 packages in 35.207s

Install work successfully, but i cant use it with this command:

ojet create test --template=navdrawer

**Returns**: 'ojet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Just to be sure we have all the info, are you on Windows 10 64-bit or 32-bit architecture?

Comment: I replied in the OracleJET GitHub issue that you opened, but here is probably easier to work on the issue. Same details if you could please.

From the root of the JET application that you created (test in the example above), can you please provide the results of these two commands:

npm -g list --depth=0 npm list --depth=0

Thanks

Comment: @DanMcGhan Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: I see you've asked this here too: https://github.com/oracle/oraclejet/issues/37 Have you tried running the commands that JB suggested? What is the output from: "npm -g list --depth=0" and "npm list --depth=0"?

Comment: @peppertech I answered there

Comment: @DanMcGhan Yes, I asked it there to reach answer quickly, I wanna to run Oracle Jet but i cant reach it. I follow instructions in getting started on the oracle site but it wont run

Answer (score 2):

It is:

```
npm install -g @oracle/ojet-cli
```

and not

```
npm -g install @oracle/oraclejet
```

You might be fetching an older version of OJET.

Answer (score 0):

The node module path might not be added to the path, kindly add it to path in environment variables

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ojet installation.

You need to install ojet. See this setup http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/globalGetStarted.html

Answer (score 0):

The command should be like this:

```
npm install -g @oracle/ojet-cli
```

and not:

```
npm -g install @oracle/ojet-cli
```